# Convert CSV to Array - Python

Tags: python

I have the following CSV file:

```
name,A,B,C
name 1,2,8,3
name 2,4,1,5
name 3,3,2,5
```

I need to separate the lines read in CSV into an array, but If I insert the array index, it returns the column, and I need to separately manipulate the row and column. How did I do?

I need it:

```
[name,A,B,C]
[name 1,2,8,3]
[name 2,4,1,5]
[name 3,3,2,5]

print(array[0])        ## The result: [name,A,B,C]
print(array[0][1])     ## The result: A
```

My Code:

```
with open(csvFileName) as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for row in csv_reader:

        myList = list(row)
        print(myList)

csv_file.close()
```

Terminal Result:

```
['name', 'Points', 'Maney', 'Coin']
['Client 1', '2', '8', '3']
['Client 2', '4', '1', '5']
['Client 3', '3', '2', '5']
```

Thank You

Comment: `myList[1:] = list(map(int, myList[1:]))`

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. It seems as if you already get what all the data you want, in the format you want. Is your issue that ``myList`` is only a single list containing only the current line instead of a list of lists of all the lines?

Comment: This list I used was just for example. My CSV has 4 rows with 4 columns. I need to get the value of each row or column using an array. If I need to get a value from row 0 column 1 I type [0][1]

Comment: Thank You aminrd, MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is how it should be?

```
myList = []
import csv
with open(csvFileName) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        myList.append(row)
    csv_file.close()

print(myList[0])
print(myList[0][1])
```